# OpenCV - Leaf Petiole Removal

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I would like to know how can I approach my given problem: removing petiole from a leaf, with very little to none effects to the leaf.

From research, people tried using morphological operations like top-hat to enhance and remove the petiole afterwards, but in some cases this doesn't work so well, detecting in addition peaks from the leaf (example below).

I will try also segmentation based on HSV color space, but i will very much appreciate an idea for BGR space.

From left to right (input image, contour found, morphological applied with a kernel size structuring element which depends for every leaf species)

I am using OpenCV with C++.

[example problem petiole detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcDKT.jpg)

Comment: Try distance transform..... it might give some insight

Comment: thanks for suggestion and edit tips :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I was curious to try this out myself.
And this is what I got:

[image]

I used the distance transform, but the final solution does not appear so perfect. I have the code in python if you would like.

CODE:

```
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(thresh1,cv2.DIST_L2,5)
ret, stalk = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.095*dist_transform.max(),255,0)

stalk = np.uint8(stalk)
cv2.imshow('stalk_removed.jpg',stalk)
```

Where `thresh1` is the binary image of the leaf.

Comment: Python would be good as well !

Comment: I've found some other methods, but this one was cool for giving me ideas; so it's okay for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. By the way, what are the other methods you found? I am interested to know.....

Comment: implemented myself a function, based on row analyzing and eliminating specific coordinates; didn't used an OpenCV function; for the moment, it works only if the petiole is at the bottom of the image, and the leaf is oriented on vertical

Comment: Cool. Do update once you conclude with a robust solution. :D

Comment: for the moment haven't worked on this subject for quite a while (optional step not a primary one in my project). i'll update if i finish the idea !